# Executing hudson specific function in jenkins pipeline

Tags: grails, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have been trying to find a solution for changing build parameters programmatically using jenkins pipeline plugin where i have jenkinsfile with following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
import hudson.model.*

properties(
    [
        parameters(
            [
                string(defaultValue: 'win64', description: 'PLATFORM', name: 'PLATFORM'),
                string(defaultValue: '12.1.0', description: 'PRODUCT_VERSION', name: 'PRODUCT_VERSION')
            ]
        )
    ]
)
stage('working with parameters'){

    node('master'){
        def thr = Thread.currentThread()
        def build = thr?.executable
        def paramsDef = build.getProperty(ParametersDefinitionProperty.class)
        if (paramsDef) {
            paramsDef.parameterDefinitions.each{ param ->
                if (param.name == 'PLATFORM') {
                println("Changing parameter ${param.name}    default value was '${param.defaultValue}' to 'osx10'")
                    param.defaultValue = "osx10"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But it fails everytime with error as :

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: executable for class: java.lang.Thread
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
```

After searching a lot i could find somewhere that this script needs to run as system groovy script and everywhere they are referring to Groovy plugin but as i am using pipeline project, i am not able to understand how can i force pipeline to execute my scripts as system groovy script.

Please solve my queries as i have left no link on google unopened :(

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do. Why can't you just change the Jenkinsfile directly to have a different `defaultValue`? This code would be executing after a build starts, and so would have no effect on the running build. But generally, trying to use Java APIs like `Thread` from a Pipeline isn't going to go well.

Comment: Actually i need to use some information (in the form of params) from previous build so these params need to be changed programmatically so that these persist and reflect in next build.
I am looking for something using which i can change the state of jenkins in pipeline, approach that i am taking seems to be not working in pipeline.